# 'If' loop in Java only returns one result

Tags: java

When I run this `if` loop program, it always returns "You're not Harry", even if I enter "Harry". I'm running Eclipse Oxygen.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hey {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner Myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        java.lang.String x;
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        x = Myscanner.nextLine();
        if (x == "Harry") {
            System.out.println("You're Harry");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You're not Harry.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: try x.equals("Harry")

Comment: Thanks, Ayush, it worked!

Comment: Hi Harry, in Java, we do not compare two strings for comparison as they are just `references` not the actual `values`. To compare two strings' values, use `equals()` (reference for this [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: Will keep it in mind, thanks!